# Using a real device to control Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

It is possible to use a real Android device to control the Android emulator?

For example, if I click at a point on the screen of the actual device, the click will also occur in the equivalent position of the display of the virtual device.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible yet!

Comment: There is no official utility that would allow you to do so. Technically, it would be possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? probably somehow. Feasible? not really. AFAIK you'd have to develop the entire system to make that work yourself.

You'd have to handle the communication (USB or bluetooth maybe?) with an app that you write.

Then you'd prolly have to change the firmware that runs the Emulator to allow for injecting your own touch events from the "listener" app that you'll also have to make and run on the emulator.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to make presentations of applications. With the emulator I can show the application on the PC screen and display the PC screen on a projector for the audience to see.

The other options to do so would directly control the emulator with the mouse (which I think does not generate the desired effect because it is not the natural way to use the device), transmit the application screen (very slow) or show the device with a webcam (which very restring my movements).

Comment: That way mentioned in my question would also facilitate the testing of devices with different screen sizes.

Comment: some devices have HDMI out, for those ones you could go device directly in to projector.